# Split csv file into 2 list depending upon column name using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split csv file into 2 lists using column name

**CSV file:**

```
Molecule Name,SMILES
ZINC53 (Aspirin),CC(=O)Oc1ccccc1C(=O)O
ZINC7460 (Vatalanib),Clc1ccc(Nc2nnc(Cc3ccncc3)c3ccccc23)cc1
ZINC1493878 (Sorafenib),CNC(=O)c1cc(Oc2ccc(NC(=O)Nc3ccc(Cl)c(C(F)(F)F)c3)cc2)ccn1
```

**Code:**

```
namelist = list()
smileslist = list()
    with open('./file.csv', 'r') as f:
        f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        columns = next(f)
        type_col1 = columns.index("Molecule Name")
        type_col2 = columns.index("SMILES")
        for column in f:     
            if type_col1 == 'Molecule Name':
                namelist.append(column)
            elif type_col2 == 'SMILES':
                smileslist.append(column)
```

Comment: Explain which result have you got with your code ?

Comment: this returns empty lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) you can do it as easily as :

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("./file.csv")
namelist = df["Molecule Name"].tolist()
smileslist = df["SMILES"].tolist()

print(namelist)
print(smileslist)
```

Or if you prefer using the csv reader you can do it as follow :

```py
import csv


namelist = list()
smileslist = list()
with open("./file.csv", "r") as f:
    f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    columns = next(f)
    index_col1 = columns.index("Molecule Name")
    index_col2 = columns.index("SMILES")
    for column in f:
        namelist.append(column[index_col1])
        smileslist.append(column[index_col2])
```